# method not allowed occuring for deleting record in .net core application working fine in web api

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

when i am posting data from postman it is successfully deleted
but i am getting error of method not allowed in .net core  controller

i am  entering  url as per postmans url

can you help me with the right method or let me know what i am doing wrong

**Code in asp.net core controller**

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult>   Delete( int id,CountryModel collection)
        {
            //try
            //{
            //    collection.DeleteCountry(collection);
            //    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            //}
            //catch
            //{
            //    return View();
            //}
            try
            {
                string message = "";
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://192.168.10.34:81/api/");

                    //HTTP POST

                    var  postTask = await client.DeleteAsync(client.BaseAddress + "Country/" + id);

                  var result  =   postTask.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    
                    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                         RedirectToAction("Index");
                    }


                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Server Error. Please contact administrator.");
                    
                    //collection.Insert(collection);                
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index"); ;
            }
        }
```

**code in web api **

```
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public PostResult Delete(int Id)
        {

            try
            {
                if (Id != 0)
                {
                    if (CountryModel.DeleteCountry(Id))
                    {
                        return new PostResult(true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return new PostResult(false);
                    }
                   
                }
                else
                {
                    return new PostResult(false);
                }
               
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return new PostResult(false);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ASP.NET Core Controller your Delete is expecting a **CountryModel**. I think you are not supplying it to the request because you don't use it.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int id, CountryModel collection)
{
}
```

You must remove it so it doesn't expect it. This is why you get the error of method not allowed. Because it can't find a method without the parameter CountryModel. Your method should look like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Delete (int id)
{
}
```

Comment: i changed it as u told  , again the same error shows

Comment: @AdityaGavali How are you calling you asp.net core controller?

Answer (score 0):

From [`HttpClient.BaseAddress` Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.baseaddress?view=net-6.0#remarks),

> When sending a HttpRequestMessage with a relative Uri, the message Uri will be added to the BaseAddress property to create an absolute Uri.
>
> Note that all characters after the right-most "/" in the base URI are excluded when combined with the message URI. See RFC 3986 Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) Generic Syntax specification.

You don't need to append `client.BaseAddress` in `client.DeleteAsync()`.

```cs
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://192.168.10.34:81/api/");

    var  postTask = await client.DeleteAsync("/Country/" + id);

    ...
}
```

Comment: i implimented it but the error remains the same  but in my create method it is "Country/" and working fine

Comment: So which part did it hit error? Are you unable to call `DELETE` for .NET Core controller or `DELETE` for WebAPI through .NET Core controller?

Comment: i guess await client.DeleteAsync

Comment: var result  =   postTask.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();  ,in result i get the 405 method not allowed

Comment: delete for web api through .net core controller

Comment: i guess it is unable to find delete method in web api from .net core controller

Comment: It worked when  added "<modules>
             <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
        </modules>" in web config file